Sync topics completion status across all courses in LearnDash
My LearnDash plugin is configured to have shared course steps, so that I can use the same lessons and topics across multiple courses. However, if a users marks a topic as complete in one particular course, it is not reflected across all courses (default setting). I want to make it such that any change in the completion status of a shared topics is reflected across all courses containing that topic.
This is the code that I used but it's not working
function nzf_sync_topic_completion($topic_data) {
    // Extract relevant data
    $topic_id = isset($topic_data['topic']->ID) ? $topic_data['topic']->ID : null;
    $course_id = isset($topic_data['course']->ID) ? $topic_data['course']->ID : 
    $user_id   = isset($topic_data['user']->ID) ? $topic_data['user']->ID : null;

    // Validate that essential data exists
    if (!$topic_id || !$course_id || !$user_id) {
        error_log('nzf_sync_topic_completion: Missing required data. Topic, course, 
        return;
    }

    // Check if LearnDash shared steps is enabled
    if (learndash_is_course_shared_steps_enabled()) {
        // Get all courses sharing the topic
        $shared_courses = learndash_get_courses_for_step($topic_id, true);

        // Loop through shared courses
        foreach ($shared_courses as $shared_course_id => $value) {
            // Skip the current course
            if ($shared_course_id == $course_id) {
                continue;
            }

            // Mark the topic as complete for the user in the shared course
            learndash_process_mark_complete($user_id, $topic_id, true, 
        }
    } else {
        error_log('nzf_sync_topic_completion: Shared steps not enabled.');
    }


// Hook into the LearnDash topic completion action
add_action('learndash_topic_completed', 'nzf_sync_topic_completion', 10, 1);

